# Deploying Dockerized MERN app on AWS Ubuntu EC2. Do I need NGINX or similar technology?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

My MERN app performs perfectly while running on Docker containers on my local machine.

When I run Docker containers, with the same images, on my AWS Ubuntu EC2 instance, the containers run, but have limited function:  It appears only the front end works, and I can only get to that with http://52.91.163.219:3000/.  I'm using MongoDB Atlas for my database.

Do I need a reverse proxy?  I keep seeing a lot of mention of using NGINX.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to my question is yes, I needed to install and configure Nginx for my deployed application to work properly.  I'm sure technologies other than Nginx would have worked, but went with it for no other reason than it seems popular.